# Setup CUDA and Pytorch for Faster-RCNN

Tags: nvidia, python, cuda

I setup cuda and pytorch with conda install pytorch==1.10.1 torchvision==0.11.2 torchaudio==0.10.1 cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch -c conda-forge. But when I run a git code it tells me that: RuntimeError: Not compiled with GPU support.

> > > import torch
> > > print(torch.version.cuda)
> > > 11.3
> > > torch.cuda.is_available()
> > > True

[output nvidia-smi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB2wF.png)
[conda list --show-channel-urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3iHd.png)

My $CUDA_HOME is not set but I don't know what I should set it to. Can someone help me what I can do? I've never worked with cuda before and therefore don't find a solution for my problem..

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows that you have **12.2** as your CUDA version, but you are installing PyTorch with an 11.3 CUDA version (by using the `cudatoolkit=11.3` flag). Check this: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-for-cuda-12/169447